# XMPP IIllegalArgumentException at Form#setAnswer("Username",true) while using UserSearchManager

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, ejabberd

I am working on android chat application using ejabberd 2.1.11. For searching whether a particular user exists or not i'm using  UserSearchManager

```
public boolean isUserExists(IrishContact ic) {
        try {
            UserSearchManager search = new UserSearchManager(connection);
            Collection<String> services = search.getSearchServices();
            if (services.isEmpty()) {
                Log.v("IrishuserSearch ", "no service found");
            }

            Log.v("service name: ", connection.getServiceName());

            Form searchForm = search.getSearchForm("vjud."
                    + connection.getServiceName());

            Form answerForm = searchForm.createAnswerForm();
            answerForm.setAnswer("Username", true);
            answerForm.setAnswer("search", ic.getPhoneNumber());
            org.jivesoftware.smackx.ReportedData data = search
                    .getSearchResults(answerForm,
                            "search." + connection.getServiceName());

            if (data.getRows() != null) {
                Iterator<Row> it = data.getRows();
                if (it.hasNext()) {
                    return true;
                } else
                    return false;
            } else
                return false;

        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;

    }
```

On the basis on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24961439/968526) answer

i'm using

> Form searchForm = search.getSearchForm("vjud."
>                     + connection.getServiceName());

instead of

> Form searchForm =
>   search.getSearchForm("search."+connection.getServiceName());

the later part was giving 503 service not found exception so i changed my code and it got solved, but now the problem is I am getting IllegalArgumentException at

> answerForm.setAnswer("Username", true);

I am using asmack-android-8-0.8.10.

```
STACK_TRACE=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field not found for the specified variable name.
at org.jivesoftware.smackx.Form.setAnswer(Form.java:258)
at com.irishtalk.utilities.IrishUserSearch.isUserExists(IrishUserSearch.java:42)

at com.irishtalk.utilities.IrishContactsHelper.addContactToDefaultRoster(IrishContactsHelper.java:51)
at com.irishtalk.utilities.IrishContactsHelper.getRoster(IrishContactsHelper.java:32)
at com.irishtalk.service.IXmppAidlStub$1.run(IXmppAidlStub.java:221)
```

can anyone help me out why this is happening? Thanks

Comment: Show us the stacktrace of the exception and tell us the version of aSmack you are using.

Comment: @Flow I have posted stack trace and library version number please look at edited question

Answer (score 0):

Ejabberd does not support the field value "Username". It is used in openfire. Please use the field vale "user" and pass arguments as string in ejabberd. Thanks. Please Vote up if your error is solved.

Comment: "user" doesn't wok for me.